# Getting malformed string error in azure cli command execution

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template, databricks, azure-cli, azure-cli2

I am trying to create Azure Databricks service using ARM template via Azure CLI.

When I ran the below command, I am getting below error,

Command to execute:-

```
az group deployment create --name adb --resource-group palmresourcegroup3 --template-file template.json --parameters parameters.json
```

Error:-

```
malformed string
```

Refer [parameters.json](https://pastebin.com/S22vFtXX)

Refer [template.json](https://pastebin.com/sXxJfs9X)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I update your storage account, your template works for me.

```
    "storageAccountName": {
        "defaultValue": "[concat('dbstorage', uniqueString(parameters('applianceName'), resourceGroup().id, subscription().id))]",
        "type": "string"
    },
```

You could check the full [template](https://gist.github.com/Walter-Shui/ed99195fe18a3d01a22c5fb2be57d740) file.

Note: Azure Databricks is in preview currently. Please ensure your subscription is enrolled in the preview. You could check on Portal.

[image]

If you subscription is not enrolled, click [here](https://databricks.azurewebsites.net/) to submit a request to enroll your subscription.

Update:

It is a version issue, when OP update CLI to `2.0.22`. The issue is solved.

Comment: I have updated defaultValue in storage account name as you suggested. But still I get same error.

Comment: @karan Do you try this template? I suggest you could test on Portal? Do you have permission to create Databricks?

Comment: I have tried this template on Portal and it works. But its throws malformed string error when I try using Azure CLI.

Comment: Hi, do you execute it on Linux or Windows, if possible, could you share your error screenshots

Comment: @karan What is your Azure CLi version? I test in 2.0.22. It works for me  fine. If possible, I suggest you could upgrade your cli to latest version or using Azure Cloud Shell.

Comment: My Azure CLI version is azure-cli (2.0.3)

Comment: Hi, I suggest you could use latest version CLI.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/160998/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-karan).

Comment: 2.0.3 is an older version. You could use `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` to upgrade the version.