# CircleCi - Azure Cli - Deployment fails

Tags: python, bash, azure, circleci, azure-cli

I'm trying to deploy to Azure with [circleci](https://circleci.com/) and a `config.yml` file using `azuresdk/azure-cli-python` from [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/azuresdk/azure-cli-python/).
I can log to Azure, set my subscription but then the followng line fails without much info.

```
#!/bin/bash -eo pipefail
az group deployment create -g Preproduction --template-file FactureResourceGroup.json --parameters FactureParametersPreproduction.json --parameters oAuthSecret=$OAUTH_SECRET
malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f2e08b6ef28>
Exited with code 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error log `malformed node or string:`, it seems you use  an older version Azure CLI.

`az -v`

The latest version is 2.0.22. If you don't use latest version, I suggest you could upgrade it with following command.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Please refer to this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47754505/getting-malformed-string-error-in-azure-cli-command-execution/47764934#47764934).

Comment: `malformed node or string: <_ast.Name object at 0x7f2e08b6ef28>`

Comment: Hi, if you json format is not right, you don't get the error log. I update my answer.

Comment: My json files are ok as they work with powershell. I'll check the cli version. Aren't image and cli versions aligned?

Comment: It seems the service you deployed older version CLI does not support.

Comment: Hi, what is the result `az -v`?

Comment: Won't be in front of my machine (I'm on phone right now) before another hour. But note that I run a docker image so the version is the one msft has put in there 

Comment: Hi, if you install Azure CLI on docker, if you could not upgrade it, you could uninstall it firstly and re-install it.  Uninstall `docker rmi -f microsoft/azure-cli` install `docker run -it azuresdk/azure-cli-python:2.0.22`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161078/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-francois).